# How to deploy an android app from React Native code using GitHub Actions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, github-actions

Error:

[image: errro]

```bash
Welcome to Gradle 6.7!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - File system watching is ready for production use
 - Declare the version of Java your build requires
 - Java 15 support

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-manifest, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /home/runner/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
         > Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

`Action.yml`

```yaml
name: Build Android
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn

      - name: Build Android Release
        run: cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

      - name: Upload Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: release
          path: android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

Repo: https://github.com/AfaqNasir/todos-app-android-action

I want to store the APK as an artifact and test that APK into my device.